# How to make the width of a grid view 100% across the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, fill-parent

I have a grid view inside my layout and I am trying to make it stretch all the way across the screen. My XML for this gridview follows below.

```
 <GridView
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:columnWidth="400dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="#fffefff9"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

The grid view does not completely fill the screens width. There are these small margins on the side. How do I get rid of these margins on the sides of the grid view completely? In other word, I want the width of the grid view to be full width. On the other hand, fill_parent does make the grid view's width cover 95% of the width of the screen, but there are small margins on the side of the screen. Unfortunately, I am not allowed to post an image since I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: You may have a padding set on the parent of the `GridView` - without the other contents of the layout, it's nearly impossible to accurately answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your list view's parent it might be a `linear layout` or `relative layout`

```
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
```

If there was already padding values change them to that.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know about the padding tag in my layout. It turns out that it was 16dp